# Converting cURL authentication to Java and retrieving & updating data using REST XML (Pt.2)

Tags: java, android, rest, curl

This is the second part of my question on converting cURL to Java
The first part is titled:

> *Converting cURL authentication to Java and retrieving & updating data using REST XML (Pt.1)*

**Third**, how can I implement update, create, and delete for the api in Java? For example:

1. Update: `curl -i -X PUT -H "Content-Type:application/xml" -H "Accept: application/xml" -d "<ticket><description>Take this description</description></ticket>" http://user:password@www.assembla.com/spaces/my_space_id/tickets/1`
2. Delete" `curl -i -X DELETE -H "Accept: application/xml" http://user:password@www.assembla.com/spaces/my_space_id/tickets/1`
3. Create: `curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/xml" -H "Accept: application/xml" -d "<ticket><summary>This is a Summary</summary><priority>3</priority></ticket>" the weblink`

In other words, how can I convert these cURL code into Java?

I would really appreciate your help. Also, a good reference to do such stuff in Java will be awesome too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the official API usually helps: [Assembla REST API](http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/breakoutdocs/Assembla_REST_API)

There is says that you need to use [basic authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication).

For accessing REST in Java: [Rest clients for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221442/rest-clients-for-java)

Comment: Thanks Peter. But my main problem is how to translate this cURL statement `curl -i -X GET -H "Accept: application/xml" http://user:password@www.assembla.com/spaces/my_space_id/tickets` into Java?

Comment: If you'd read the links you'd know: use Jersey client library, set it to use basic authentication and call `www.assembla.com/spaces/my_space_id/tickets` url.

Comment: This link explains all the steps in one page (including Basic Authentication): http://blogs.sun.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/consuming_restful_web_services_with

Answer (score 0):

you should be looking out for Apache HttpClient tutorials.

There's some Samplecode of a Android Rest Client application around, try searching for it. Also, I just discovered ["resting"](http://code.google.com/p/resting/wiki/TwoMinuteTutorial). I haven't tried it, but might be worth a look.

Also watching the [Developing Android REST client applications](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/developing-RESTful-android-apps.html) video from Google.io is recommended, as it is teaching some very important architectural basics and hints.

I placed a similar question some time ago, and got an answer [here at Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188621/how-to-setup-administrators-in-couchdb-via-apaches-httpclient-given-a-curl-exam).

Comment: Thanks. I was able to authenticate successfully and retrieve (GET) data. Now I am having problem with (POST). I don't know how to invoke XML in POST. Example: curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/xml" -H "Accept: application/xml" -d "<ticket><summary>This is a Summary</summary><priority>3</priority></ticket>" the weblink